# If statement not working LCD and Joystick

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Right now, I am trying to make a Stickman on the lcd with a joystick that controls the stickman. If the joystick is HIGH, then the stickman is supposed to turn into text saying "Hello!".
When I try doing this, it just shows the stickman and nothing else. I try moving the joystick, and still nothing. What is going on?

Code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int state = digitalRead(8);

LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);

byte customChar[] = {
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B01110,
  B00100,
  B01110,
  B10101,
  B00100,
  B01010
};


void setup() {
  
   lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.createChar(0, customChar);
  lcd.home();
  lcd.write(static_cast<uint8_t>(0));
}

void loop() {
  for(int position = 0; position < 13; position++) {
  lcd.scrollDisplayRight();
  delay(150);

  
  
    if (state == HIGH) {

    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Hello!");
    }
  }
}
```

The wiring was double checked, and i am sure its correct.

Comment: You only initialize or assign to `state` *once* in your program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read in a value for the state variable in the loop.
for example, you can put:

```
void loop() {
   for(int position = 0; position < 13; position++) {
      lcd.scrollDisplayRight();
      delay(150);
   }

   state = digitalRead(8);

   if (state == HIGH) {
     lcd.clear();
     lcd.print("Hello!");
   }
}
```

This should work. Try it out!

Comment: It still doesnt work... Maybe there might be another solution?

Comment: @HamTheCoder try state == True in the if